# Windows Blue Screen Like Problem in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, kernel, 13.10, atheros, wpa-supplicant

Facing this weired problem in ubuntu 13.04. Even after upgrading to 13.10 the problem exists.

Its appear like windows blue screen. Suddenly this screen appears. I had to push the Powerbutton for seconds to shutdown the PC and start it again.

[image: Error screenshot 2]"

[image: Error screenshot 1]

Comment: Harware problems also creates this.(If so, not relates to here). Somehow Check the monitor cable.(while in use)

Comment: Does this happen on every reboot? Can you disable wireless network?

Comment: i am using toshiba laptop, no problem with monitor. not its not happen on every reboot, suppose 2-3 month in a month at least.

Answer (score -1):

Aat what point of use does this happen?
You can try the re-install the kernel

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/linux-kernel-3-12-released-install-ubuntu-or-linux-mint/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.